# Android Studio (Category, Firebase)

Tags: android-studio, firebase-database

Добрый день(Вечер/ночь), у меня есть одна проблемка. Вообщем, картинки и текст в категории из Firebase загружаются только после выключения и включения экрана. Вот мой код из CategoryFragment:

```
package com.example.home.onlinequiz;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.home.onlinequiz.Interface.ItemClickListener;
import com.example.home.onlinequiz.Model.Category;
import com.example.home.onlinequiz.VievHolder.CategoryVievHolder;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;


public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

    View myFragment;

    RecyclerView listCategory;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Category,CategoryVievHolder> adapter;

    FirebaseDatabase database;

    DatabaseReference categories;

    public static CategoryFragment newInstance() {
        CategoryFragment categoryFragment = new CategoryFragment();
        return categoryFragment;
    }





    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        categories = database.getReference("Category");


    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category,container,false);
        listCategory = (RecyclerView)myFragment.findViewById(R.id.listCategory);
        listCategory.setHasFixedSize(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(container.getContext());
        listCategory.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        loadCategories();
        return myFragment;
    }

    private void loadCategories() {
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Category,CategoryVievHolder>(
                Category.class,
                R.layout.category_layout,
                CategoryVievHolder.class,
                categories
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(CategoryVievHolder viewHolder, final Category model, int position) {
                viewHolder.category_name.setText(model.getName());
                Picasso.with(getActivity())
                        .load(model.getImage())
                        .into(viewHolder.category_image);

                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view, int position, boolean isLongClick) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.format("%s|%s",adapter.getRef(position).getKey(),model.getName()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
        };
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        listCategory.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    private void Categories() {
    }
}
Просьба помочь, заранее спасибо.
```

Comment: Окей, спасибо за ответы, а то думал что вообще не кто не ответит. Буду ждать ответа завтра, надеюсь дождусь.

Comment: А как это сделать? А то я плохо понял, можете по подробнее пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите следующую строчку:

```
listCategory.setHasFixedSize(true);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!